# How to associate loadBalancingRules, listener and probs in an addition template to an existing load balancer on Azure cloud?

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer, infrastructure-as-code

I have created an Azure load balancer with Azure resource manager template, but could not figure out how to associate new listeners, rules and probes defined in an extra template to the existing load balancer.

The motive to do this is utilizing one load balancer to route traffic to several applications running on the same virtual machine scale set through different port.

Comment: Do you want to link an extra Azure LB configuration template2 to existing Azure load balancer template1?

Comment: @NancyXiong yes. So I can get the flexibility of configuring the rules, probes and listeners while do not have to messing around the main configuration of the load balancer.